# Parent class is not defined

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a parent class, `HTTPConnection`, that I want to use as a network util class to reduce code repetition but when I try to use it, `core.umd.js` says `Uncaught ReferenceError: HTTPConnection is not defined` but it is defined which confuses me.

My `HTTPConnection` class:

```
import {Response, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

export class HTTPConnection {
    protected static addAuthorizationHeader(token: string, reqOptionsArgs?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (reqOptionsArgs) {
            reqOptionsArgs.headers.append('Authorization', token);
            return reqOptionsArgs;
        }

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', token);
        return {headers: headers};
    }

    //Copied from the Angular 2 Developer Guide - HTTP Client
    protected static extractData(res: Response) {
        return res.json || {};
    }

    protected static handleError (error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = "Error: " + (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

The service that extends it:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {HTTPConnection} from "./http.connection";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CoursesService extends HTTPConnection {

    private token: string = "pew";

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        super();
    }

    getCourses(): Observable<Response> {
        return this._http.get('https://httpbin.org/get', HTTPConnection.addAuthorizationHeader(this.token))
        .map(HTTPConnection.extractData)
        .catch(HTTPConnection.handleError);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone would help me with this

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you use inheritance, and thus force every user of HTTPConnection to extend it and nothing else, just to provide static utility functions. Why not just define a class with public static funtions, or even just top-level utility functions?

Comment: @JBNizet It doesn't really matter that much to me because either way it still throws that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was some weird compilation error (not sure if TypeScript or Angular 2 error) where one of the classes still had the reference to `HTTPConnection` even though it wasn't being used in it.